# Base class and templates

Tags: c++

Can I write code like this (tried it and doesn't compile in VS2015):

```
template<class BaseClassT>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClassT
{
...
};
```

and then use it like:

```
class BaseClass
{
};

DeriveClass<BaseClass> c;
```

if not possible, is there a way to implement the same idea?

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the full error message

Comment: `DeriveClass` does not exist...

Comment: `DeriveClass<BaseClass> c;` Did you mean `DerivedClass<BaseClass> c;`? Is it a typo?

Comment: CRTP:  Curiously Reoccurring Template Pattern?  I've just heard it called the Curiously Reoccurring pattern.  The most notable use I can think of is with code generation where some template sits on top of a pile of generated base classes.

Comment: What idea? We cannot know what your idea is solely from code that, by your own admission, does not achieve that thing. Use words to explain your goal.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I need more coffee.

Comment: Thanks guys. I had a more complicated case, where I was using multiple inheritance... I thought I wasn't doing the right thing.

Comment: Good reason to create a proper [MCVE] .... you posted something that does not have a [real] problem, wasting everybody's time (including yours)...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may use a template argument as base, and [it compiles in MSVS if you fix the typo](https://godbolt.org/z/qr4_rE).

<sub>(Note that this is *not* the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), despite what you may have heard.)</sub>

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what the point of this question is. Is there anything you cannot do with a template (class) argument you could do with other classes?

Comment: @Ayxan Nothing springs to mind